# When does averaging affect a linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

### Given the following:

**data $(x_{data},y_{data})$**, where x values may be measured multiple times. 
For example,
$$ x_{data} = ( 1, 2, 2, 3,3,3, 4 ) $$
$$ y_{data}=(8,10,9,1,2,1.5,−7) $$

**And a fitting function that's linear in fit parameters**  
For example, $$f(x) = a + b \cos(x) + c \sin(x)$$
This function is not necessarily linear in the variables. (i.e it's not necessarily  $g(x) =  m*x + c$) .

### I could perform a fit a few ways:

1. Directly on the data $(x_{data},y_{data})$
2. On the average of each y for a given x. In the example: $$x_{avg} = (1,2,3,4)$$ and $$y_{avg} = (8,9.5,1.5,4)$$
3. Or on the averaged data set with the same number of points $x_{data}$ and $$y_{avgSpaced} = (8,9.5,9.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,4)$$

### My Guess

I feel like method 2 will result in a different fit from 1 and 3, because the weighting of the points is different. In the example, x=3 matters less if you do method 2 than method 1 or 3. However, I imagine a least squares regression with weighting would make method 2 equivalent to method 3. And my intuition tells me that method 3 should be equivalent to method 1.

### Is this correct?

Comment: Method $3$ is essentially method $2$ with non-uniform weights, as you mentioned. However, method $3$ is NOT equivalent to method $1$. For example, change $10$ and $9$ from the data into $9.5+10^{12}$ and $9.5-10^{12}$ respectively. Method $3$ will not be affected as the average remains the same. However, method $1$ is affected heavily since if the regression line does not pass through $(2,9.5)$, the squared error will be huge

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja, I agree the mean square error will be huge, but the fit parameters themselves I'd imagine could plausibly still be the same.

Comment: The mean square error for two points spaced some distance d vertically apart checks out.
the y values would be $\bar{y}+d $ and  $\bar{y} - d$.  Then the sum of the squares of differences from a fit value f would be: $2(f^2 + \bar{y}^2+d^2 - 2\bar{y}f)$. Notably the f derivative of this is independent of d, although the overall size is different.

Comment: Ok, I think I have a proof that method 3 would give the same fit as method 1, and would approach the same fit if using a nonlinear fitting algorithm.